# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Currently working on a string in C#.

Example:

```
07.02.2011 17:24:17 [/sbc_DIG] [ERROR] CommandExecutionService:290 - Error during command execution
```

I can't split using spaces as in somecase there will spaces inside squarebracet

In this case I'm interested in getting `07.02.2011`, `17:24:17` and `CommandExecutionService:290` using regex

---

Solution based on Ikegami answer

```
@"^(?[0-9.]+) (?[0-9:]+) [.?] [.?] (?[a-zA-Z0-9:]+)\s";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perl syntax, but the regex pattern should be the same in C#,

```
my ($date, $time, $pos) = $line =~ /
   ^
   (\S+) \s+
   (\S+) \s+
   \[ [^\]]* \] \s+
   \[ [^\]]* \] \s+
   (\S+)
/x;
```

Comment: your previous solution really helped ..I worked out on it and modified ..thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome, @pjm. If you're satisfied with what you have, accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just split on spaces for the first four fields and then take the first word of the last field?

It looks like your data is really structured like:

```
<date>(space)<time>(space)<URL?>(space)<severity/log level>(space)<message>
```

So just split it into those components by splitting on spaces:

```
string[] fields = myString.split(" ", 4);
```

Comment: some times there will spaces in the squarebracets

Example
07.02.2011 17:24:17 [/sbc_DIG] [ ERROR] CommandExecutionService:290 - test

so I cant split with spaces as u can see there is space inside squarebracet

Comment: I suspect the use of square brackets is the result of the possibility of spaces in the square brackets.